# Select trazendo máximo de Colunas com algo Escrito - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Galera, tenho a seguinte estrutura numa tabela MySql:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://prnt.sc/k0d0ev

Preciso fazer um select que me traga o máximo de postos que tenha algum registro, por exemplo, na referência 269 me traga até o posto 4, e na referência 258 me traga até posto 6.

Pode ser algo parecido com o MAX, mas que me traga o máximo de colunas que tenha algum registro daquela referência. Como posso fazer este select?

Comment: você tem 10 colunas pra registrar cada posto, é isso ?!

Comment: Isso mesmo.....

Comment: Caso você venda seu sistema um dia, quem sabe, para uma média indústria que tenha 216 operações não-lineares, você vai criar 206 colunas a mais e deixar algumas do meio vazias??

Comment: Esse sistema agora está sendo desenvolvida especificamente para uma empresa com setor de montagem de brinquedos, onde o máximo de postos são 20, e sempre é linear... estou usando essa tabela como base para montar para eles o método operacional, ondei irão cadastrar o método e depois visualizar, com foto e descrição, pois atualmente a empresa (como é de pequeno porte e não investe muito em tecnologia), registra tudo em planilha excel, e não existem métodos operacionais cadastrados. Mas se você tiver alguma sugestão para auxiliar a estrutura da tabela, eu agradeço a sugestão! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um `IF`, se houver algo escrito adiciona 1 senão adiciona 0. Esse `IF` terá que ser feito para cada coluna, exemplo:

```
SELECT a.`REFERENCIA`, a.`DESCRICAO`, (
  IF(a.`POSTO1` <> '', 1, 0) +
  IF(a.`POSTO2` <> '', 1, 0) +
  IF(a.`POSTO3` <> '', 1, 0) +
  IF(a.`POSTO4` <> '', 1, 0) +
  IF(a.`POSTO5` <> '', 1, 0) +
  IF(a.`POSTO6` <> '', 1, 0) +
  IF(a.`POSTO7` <> '', 1, 0) +
  IF(a.`POSTO8` <> '', 1, 0) +
  IF(a.`POSTO9` <> '', 1, 0) +
  IF(a.`POSTO10` <> '', 1, 0)
) AS qtde
FROM nome_da_tabela a
```

Essa tabela não esta com uma estrutura adequada para um banco de dados relacional, Esses postos, deveriam estar em outra tabela com a referência dessa tabela.

Comment: Sim, é que estou aqui no meu PC no trabalho, e esse projeto tenho separado no meu notebook, ai me surgiu essa dúvida e só simulei aqui rapidinho, mas no meu projeto mesmo tenho uma tabela de referências e postos separados, com primary e foreign keys :)... e obrigado pela resposta, não tinha pensado nesse jeito, irei testar e lhe respondo se atendeu ou não meu problema!

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e atende o que eu preciso! Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Pra que o `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Também não vi sentido no group by, eu retirei ele

Comment: É que inicialmente pensei em fazer com `SUM`, mas mudei de ideia e o `GROUP BY` acabou ficando, vou retirar.

Comment: Ah blz sahsuahsua

Answer (score 0):

Esta consulta funciona no MySQL 8.x.

Ela traz a referência, o status do posto (conteúdo das colunas `posto1`..`posto10`) e o maior número do posto.

Ela ignora qualquer vazio que tenha nessas colunas `postoX` e desconsidera descontinuidades nessas colunas (por exemplo, `posto1` e `posto3` vazios e `posto2` e `posto4` cheios - no caso, o maior posto será `4`).

```
WITH q (referencia, statusposto, numposto) AS
(
    SELECT referencia, posto1, 1
    FROM tabela
    WHERE posto1 IS NOT NULL AND posto1 <> ''

    UNION

    SELECT referencia, posto2, 2
    FROM tabela
    WHERE posto2 IS NOT NULL AND posto2 <> ''

    UNION

    ...

    UNION

    SELECT referencia, posto10, 10
    FROM tabela
    WHERE posto10 IS NOT NULL AND posto2 <> ''
)
SELECT q.referencia, q.numposto maiorposto, q.statusposto
FROM q
JOIN (
    SELECT q.referencia, MAX(q.numposto) maiorposto
    FROM q
    GROUP BY q.referencia) r ON r.referencia = q.referencia
                            AND r.maiorposto = q.numposto
```

Answer (score -2):

count() com group by

```
select referencia, count() as qtd
from tabela
group by referencia
```